# Calculate average for specific rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, average, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following two tables:

`content:`

```
| id | name  | created_by |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  | test  |     me     |
| 2  | test2 |     me     |
| 3  | test3 |     you    |
| 4  | test4 |     me     |
```

`like_dislike:`

```
| id | content_id | like | dislike |
+----+------------+------+---------+
| 1  |     1      |  1   |    0    |
| 2  |     2      |  1   |    0    |
| 3  |     2      |  0   |    0    |
```

I need to calculate the average likes of the last 2 content rows where `created_by = me`.

So for example, the last two content_ids are 2 and 4.

The like_dislike table has records for content_id 2, with a row where like is 1 and a row where like is 0, so the average is 1/2.

I have tried the following query but it will not work:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM `like_dislike` 
   WHERE `like`='1' AND `content_id`= pi.id) / (COUNT(*))
FROM content AS pi 
WHERE pi.create_by = 'me' 
ORDER BY pi.id DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Why is content_id 4 not in your like_dislike table? Also, why is id 2 repeated? Please double check that table and I can try to help you solve this.

Comment: `content_id=pi.id` what is `pi`? and shouldn't it be `like_dislike.content_id` instead of just `content_id`

Comment: cause 2 user liked content_id but content_ud 4 have no like @McAdam331

Comment: @halkhabi so are you saying 'id' represents the content that was liked/disliked? What does 'content_id' represent then?

Comment: if user do not like any content then he have no chance to dislike @McAdam331

Comment: @halkhabi nice edit, I understand a little better now. Typing up answer.

Comment: sorry I have some mistake to type in example like_dislike table. please check now. @McAdam331

Comment: @Halkhabi did any of these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.* 
     , AVG(liked) 
  FROM content x 
  JOIN content y
    ON y.created_by = x.created_by 
   AND y.id >= x.id 
  JOIN like_dislike z
    ON z.content_id = x.id
 WHERE x.created_by = 'me' 
 GROUP BY x.id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT y.id) <= 2;
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're trying to do here also, even though you might not see it, is getting the greatest-n-per-group. See this [article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) for more information.

So, what I would do is start by getting the latest two `content` rows that are created by you, like so:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM content c
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM content co
  WHERE co.created_by = c.created_by AND co.id >= c.id) <= 2
AND c.created_by = 'me';
```

The next part I will step through a little slower because it is kind of tricky. You can join the above with the like_dislike table on the condition that the content_id matches, so you can view the total likes for each of your last two posts:

```
SELECT c.*, ld.*
FROM content c
JOIN like_dislike ld ON ld.content_id = c.id
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM content co
  WHERE co.created_by = c.created_by AND co.id >= c.id) <= 2
AND c.created_by = 'me';
```

Once you have that, you can use the `AVG()` function to get the average likes, and group by each content_id, like this:

```
SELECT c.id, AVG(ld.liked) AS averageLikes
FROM content c
JOIN like_dislike ld ON ld.content_id = c.id
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM content co
  WHERE co.created_by = c.created_by AND co.id >= c.id) <= 2
AND c.created_by = 'me'
GROUP BY c.id;
```

One important thing to note here: This will only show the post that has activity associated with it. In other words, content_id 4 will not appear. If you need to see it, you can do a LEFT JOIN, and check if the average is null and replace it with 0 if it is, like this:

```
SELECT c.id, IFNULL(AVG(ld.liked), 0) AS averageLikes
FROM content c
LEFT JOIN like_dislike ld ON ld.content_id = c.id
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM content co
  WHERE co.created_by = c.created_by AND co.id >= c.id) <= 2
AND c.created_by = 'me'
GROUP BY c.id;
```

And here is your [SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43d966/3)

**ALSO NOTE** `like` is a reserved word in MySQL, so I changed the two columns in the fiddle to be `liked` and `disliked`. I recommend you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want this information for one user at a time, then you don't need to do fancy things with self joins or variables.  You can just use `limit` in a subquery:

```
select avg(like)
from like_dislike ld join
     (select c.*
      from content c
      where c.create_by = 'me'
      order by id
      limit 2
     ) c2
     on ld.content_id = c2.id;
```